# PHP cURL Content-Length

Tags: php, php-curl

I am trying to add a record to the database with POST operation via API and I generated the attached code from Postman.
On Postman, the process goes without any problem and user registration takes place.
But when I try to generate the code as "PHP cURL" via Postman and run it on PHP, I get the relevant error.

> HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.

I defined **POSTFIELDS** as array, calculated **Content-Length** using **strlen** function and added it to **Headers**. But it didn't work.

**My PHP code;**

`````
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://xxx.xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
    "TokenKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "EmployeeList": [
        {
            "Example1": "1",
            "Example2": "somedata2",
            "Example3": "somedata3",
            "Example4": "somedata4",
            "Example5": "somedata5",
            "Example6": "somedata6",
            "Example7": "somedata7",
            "Example8": "somedata8",
            "Example9": "somedata9",
            "Example10": "somedata10",
            "Example11": "somedata11",
            "Example12": "somedata12",
            "Example13": "somedata13",
            "Example14": "somedata14",
            "Example15": "somedata15",
            "Example16": "somedata16",
            "Example17": "somedata17",
            "Example18": "somedata18",
            "Example19": "somedata19",
            "Example20": "somedata20",
            "Example21": "somedata21",
            "Example22": "somedata22",
            "Example23": "somedata23",
            "Example24": "somedata24",
            "Example25": "somedata25",
            "Example26": "somedata26",
            "Example27": "somedata27",
            "Example28": "somedata28",
            "Example29": "somedata29",
            "Example30": "somedata30",
            "Example31": "somedata31",
            "Example32": null,
            "Example33": null,
            "Example34": null,
            "Example35": "2022-12-06 22:05:22",
            "Example36": false,
            "Example37": true
        }
    ]
}',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  ),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
echo "<br>";
echo $statusCode;````
`````

Comment: Well, that request clearly doesn't have a content length. So you probably added it in some other code, but guessing what you did there isn't helpful. Please, provide a [mcve]. Also, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Do you have UTF-8 multibytes charactes in your data? You can still try using `mb_strlen` to see if it works..

Comment: @Kaddath Data array length is 1537 with "mb_strlen", but when I give this value to Content-Length, I don't get any response from cURL